# Есть ли возможность запустить SignalR сервер на Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, signalr

Я участвую в проекте, где за мной клиентская сторона чата на win. Ищу лучший способ. Наткнулся на SignalR, но не могу найти возможность реализации на Linux-сервере. Неужели придется отбросить почти готовое решение?

Если что-то не понятно:
Я делаю чат под win. Сервер будет разрабатываться кем-то другим под linux. Для меня было бы идеально, если бы я мог общаться с сервером через SignalR. Желательно используя WebSocket-транспорт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно если серверная часть будет разрабатываться на SignalR для .Net Core. 
SignalR .Net Standard 2.0 уже доступна.
https://habr.com/post/338490/

Comment: Не совсем понял. Такая серверная часть может быть размещена на Linux?

Comment: @АлександрЛи .Net Core - кроссплатформенный, в том числе и Linux через Apachi или Nginx сервер.

Comment: Да, используя .Net Standard можно писать под Linux и другие OS https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/net-standard и https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/